# Functions separting points in Hausdorff spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

A colleague in algebra asked me this, and I couldn't answer it.  On the [Wikipedia page for "epimorphism"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism) it is claimed that in the category of Hausdorff spaces and continuous maps, a function is epi if and only if it has dense range.  The "if" case is easy, but I couldn't justify the "only if" case.

This boils down to: let Y be a Hausdorff space, and let X in Y be a closed subset not equal to Y, and not empty.  Can you find a Hausdorff space Z and functions f,g:Y->Z such that f and g agree on X, but are not equal.  <strike>I think, by using a quotient argument, you can assume that X is just a point.</strike>

Comment: I am not convinced you can reduce the general case to one where X is a point. You would need better separation than Hausdorff, or the quotient may not be Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's right: if you collapse X to a point x then it's not clear that you can separate x from other points.

Comment: If you can reduce to the case of a point, then you are done. Take Y=Z, f to be 
the identity and g to be the map sending all of Y to the point X. So all the
challenge is in that reduction step.

Comment: @frb: Your second map is likely to be discontinuous.

Comment: Answer withdrawn: sorry, missed the obvious fact that the map isn't open!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a Hausdorff space, and let $X\subset Y$ be a closed subspace. Consider disjoint union of two copies of $Y$, and let $Z$ be the coequalizer of two embeddings of $X$ into it
(that is, we glue two copies of $Y$ along $X$). Clearly, the two natural maps $\iota_{1,2}:Y\to Z$ coincide only on $X$. It is easy to see that $Z$ is Hausdorff.

Indeed, take $z_1,z_2\in Z$, $z_1\ne z_2$. The map $p:Z\to Y$ is continuous, so if $p(z_1)\ne p(z_2)$, we can take preimages of open neighborhoods of $p(z_1)$ and $p(z_2)$ to separate $z_1$ and $z_2$. It remains to deal with the case $z_{1,2}=\iota_{1,2}(y)$ for $y\in  Y-X$.
But the neighborhoods $\iota_{1,2}(Y-X)$ work.

Answer (score 9):

This is really a comment on t3suji's answer, but it's too long to be a comment as such.

t3suji's answer is the canonical one in the following precise sense.  Let $e: X \to Y$ be a morphism in any category.  It's an elementary exercise to show that the following conditions on $e$ are equivalent:

1. $e$ is an epimorphism
2. the square 
   $$
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   X    &\stackrel{e}{\to} &Y \\
   e\downarrow &                  &\downarrow 1_Y \\
   Y    &\stackrel{1_Y}{\to} &Y
   \end{array}
   $$
   is a pushout
3. for some morphism $f: Y \to Z$, the square
   $$
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   X    &\stackrel{e}{\to} &Y \\
   e\downarrow &                  &\downarrow f \\
   Y    &\stackrel{f}{\to} &Z
   \end{array}
   $$
   is a pushout.

I'll only use the equivalence 1 $\iff$ 3 here.  The other implications are just scene-setting.

Suppose we want to show that a particular morphism $e$ is *not* epi.  Assuming that there are enough pushouts around, we can argue as follows.  Form the pushout square
 $$
\begin{array}{ccc}
X    &\stackrel{e}{\to} &Y \\
e\downarrow &                  &\downarrow f \\
Y    &\stackrel{g}{\to} &Z.
\end{array}
$$
If $f \neq g$ then the implication 1 $\Rightarrow$ 3 tells us that $e$ is not epi.  Moreover, this strategy is bound to work, in the sense that if $f = g$ then the implication 3 $\Rightarrow$ 1 tells us that $e$ is epi after all.

It only remains to see that this is indeed what t3suji did.  In his/her situation, $e$ was the inclusion $X \to Y$.  He/she then took the coequalizer of the two obvious maps $X \to Y + Y$ (where $+$ means coproduct, i.e. disjoint union).  For elementary and totally general reasons, this is the same thing as taking the pushout just mentioned.  The morphisms that t3suji called $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$, I called $f$ and $g$.  Finally, although t3suji's pushout is in the category of *all* topological spaces, he/she then verified that the space $Z$ is indeed Hausdorff, from which it follows that it's also a pushout in Hausdorff spaces.

So now you know, in principle, how to answer any question of the form "prove that such-and-such a morphism isn't epi".

Comment: Of course, in general *the Principle of Conservation of the Difficulty under Changes in the Statement* will probably kick in in most cases!

Comment: Mariano, you mean that rephrasing a question in a different language never makes it fundamentally easier?  I don't think I agree, and that wasn't the point of my answer.  I was just observing that t3suji's answer (man, typing that name is giving me trouble) embodies some kind of universal method for solving these problems.

Comment: Yep: I think this is a very nice observation by Tom.  Actually, I sat in on an algebra grad course last year which dealt with some of this homological algebra.  This popped into my mind immediately upon seeing t3suji's answer.  So I think I disagree with Mariano: if someone had said "pushout" to me, and walked away, I think I would have come up with t3suji's idea pretty quickly...

Comment: @Tom Leinster: (man, typing that name is giving me trouble) Sorry for that --- I somehow got so used to it that I have entered it in Math Overflow without much thought. It feels sort of silly to change it now... 
@Matthew Daws: It's interesting that somehow pushouts are not the first thought after reading the original problem (at least not for me). So maybe Tom's beautiful abstract set-up should help me see it next time I run across it.